ERROR Error during sign in: [com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: DEVELOPER_ERROR]. Using without firebase. Trying to signing with google
I'm using Google Sign-In with the following setup:
Library: react-native-google-signin/google-signin: 13.1.0
React Native version: 0.75.4
Credentials: I've added the required OAuth 2.0 credentials for web, Android, and iOS.
Google Sign-In Configuration:
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: 'Web Client ID',
  iosClientId: 'iOS Client ID',
  offlineAccess: true,
  forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
  profileImageSize: 120,
  scopes: ['email', 'profile']
});

However, I keep getting the DEVELOPER_ERROR when I click the Google Sign-In button.
I've already tried the solution mentioned in this GitHub issue, but it didn't work for me.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?
